# Why `f x = x x` and `g x = x x x x x` have the same type

Tags: haskell

I'm playing with Rank-N-type and trying to type `x x`. But I find it counter intuitive that these two functions can be typed in the same way.

```hs
f :: (forall a b. a -> b) -> c
f x = x x

g :: (forall a b. a -> b) -> c
g x = x x x x x
```

I have also noticed that something like `f x = x x ... x x` (many `x`s) still has the same type.
Can anyone explain why it is the case?

Comment: `forall a b. a -> b` is a function that takes *any* type as an argument and returns *anything*, at the caller's behest. It can be used in any context a function can, because it can specialize to any function type, but good luck ever constructing an instance of it that isn't either `undefined` or `unsafeCoerce`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## A simpler example

This is a phenomenon that can be observed whenever we use a variable which has a polymorphic type (like your `x`). The identity function `id` is perhaps the most famous example.

```
id :: forall a . a -> a
```

Here, all these expressions type check, and have type `Int -> Int`:

```
id :: Int -> Int
id id :: Int -> Int
id id id :: Int -> Int
id id id id :: Int -> Int
...
```

How is that possible? Well, the crux is that each time we write `id` we are actually meaning "the identity function on some unknown type `a` that should be inferred from the context". Crucially, each use of `id` has its own `a`.

Let's write `id @T` to mean the specific identity function on type `T`.

Writing

```
id :: Int -> Int
```

actually means

```
id @Int :: Int -> Int
```

which is straightforward. Instead, writing

```
id id :: Int -> Int
```

actually means

```
id @(Int -> Int) (id @Int) :: Int -> Int
```

where the first `id` now refers to the function space `Int -> Int`! And, of course,

```
id id id :: Int -> Int
```

means

```
(id @((Int -> Int) -> (Int -> Int))) (id @(Int -> Int)) (id @Int) :: Int -> Int
```

And so on. We do not realize that types get that messy since Haskell infers those for us.

## The specific case

In your specific case,

```
g :: (forall a b. a -> b) -> c
g x = x x x x x
```

we can make that type check in many ways. A possible way is to define `A ~ Int`, `B ~ Bool`, `T ~ (A -> B)` and then infer:

```
g x = x @T @(T -> T -> T -> c) (x @A @B) (x @A @B) (x @A @B) (x @A @B)
```

I suggest to spend some time to realize that everything type checks. (Moreover our choices of `A` and `B` are completely arbitrary, and we could use any other types there. We could even use distinct `A`s and `B`s for each `x`, as long as the first `x` is suitably instantiated!)

It is then obvious that such inference is also possible even when `x x x ...` is a longer sequence.

Answer (score 7):

The key is that `x :: a -> b` is a function that can provide a value of *any* type, no matter what argument is given. That means `x` can be applied to itself, and the result can be applied to `x` again, and so on and so on.

At least, that's what it promises the type checker it can do. The type checker isn't concerned about whether or not any such value *exists*, only that the types align. Neither `f` nor `g` can actually be called, because no such value of type `a -> b` exists (ignoring bottom and `unsafeCoerce`).

Answer (score 3):

This shouldn't really be any more surprising than the fact that

```
m :: (∀ a . a) -> (∀ a . a) -> (Int, Bool)
m p q = (p, q)
```

has the same type as

```
n :: (∀ a . a) -> (∀ a . a) -> (Int, Bool)
n p q = (q, p)
```

Much like in your example, this works because the universally-quantified argument can be used in lots of different way, with the compiler in each case choosing an appropriate type and enforcing `x` to act as having that type.

This is actually a rather contrived situation because types like `∀ a . a` or `∀ a b . a->b` are uninhabited (modulo ⊥), so you would never actually be able to *use* a RankN function with such an argument; pragmatically you wouldn't even *write* it either then!

Practically useful RankN functions usually impose some extra structure or typeclass constraint in their arguments, like

```
foo :: (∀ a . [a] -> [a]) -> ...
```

or

```
qua :: (∀ n . Num n => Int -> n -> n) -> ...
```